# How to overlap (mach) and clip a radar image with a shapefile in python

Tags: python, numpy, gdal, netcdf, shapely

I was wandering if someone could help me with the following issue. In advance, I really appreciate it.
I have a shapefile and a radar image. But they are in different coordinate systems. The radar image is a NetCDF file which covers a part of the shapefile. I want to know how can overlap (match) them together and clip the radar image from the shapefile.
The coordinate system of shapefile and radar image is shown in the following.

Coordinate systems of the shapefile:
left 2126960.000000 m,
right 2938920.000000 m,
top 2825210.000000 m,
bottom 2262400.000000 m,
Projected Coordinate System:    GDA_1994_Lambert_Conformal_Conic,
Projection: Lambert_Conformal_Conic,
False_Easting:  2500000.00000000,
False_Northing: 2500000.00000000,
Central_Meridian:   145.00000000,
Standard_Parallel_1:    -36.00000000,
Standard_Parallel_2:    -38.00000000,
Latitude_Of_Origin: -37.00000000,
Linear Unit:    Meter,
Geographic Coordinate System:   GCS_GDA_1994,
Datum:  D_GDA_1994,
Prime Meridian:     Greenwich,
Angular Unit:   Degree,

Coordinate system, y, y_bound, x, x_bound of the radar image,
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>,
int8 proj(),
grid_mapping_name: albers_conical_equal_area,
standard_parallel: [-36.3 -39.4],
longitude_of_central_meridian: 144.752,
latitude_of_projection_origin: -37.852,
false_easting: 0.0,
false_northing: 0.0,
semi_major_axis: 6378137.0,
semi_minor_axis: 6356752.31414,
unlimited dimensions:
current shape = (),
filling off,

Y
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>,
float64 y(y),
standard_name: projection_y_coordinate,
units: km,
bounds: y_bounds,
unlimited dimensions:
current shape = (512,),

Y_bound,
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float64 y_bounds(y, n2),
unlimited dimensions:
current shape = (512, 2),
filling off,
filling off,

X,
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float64 x(x),
standard_name: projection_x_coordinate,
units: km,
bounds: x_bounds,
unlimited dimensions:
current shape = (512,),
filling off,

X_bound,
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float64 x_bounds(x, n2),
unlimited dimensions:
current shape = (512, 2),
filling off

Comment: What have you tried yourself? There's many libraries out there that allow you to combine data sources with difference CRS, if you share your own attempts, someone should be able to help with issues you're having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need help with transforming geometries from different coordinate systems into a common one you can use pyproj for example.
You will first need to find the epsg codes of the coordinate systems the original data is defined in. You can find them here https://spatialreference.org/ref/?search=lambert+conformal+conic&srtext=Search. In the example below i already tried to use the right ones but please double check.

```
from pyproj import CRS
from shapely.geometry import box
from shapely.ops import transform


crs_shapefile = CRS("EPSG:3112")
crs_radar = CRS("EPSG:3577")

transformer = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs(
            crs_from=crs_shapefile,
            crs_to=crs_radar,
        )

example_geometry = box(0,0,1,1)
transformed_box = transform(func=transformer.transform, geom=example_geometry)
```